# JavaScript with Ajax with HTTP request outputs undefined display 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a local chat application my problem is that it displays undefined result then works fine after display all data.

here's the code:

```
function chatDisplay(){
        if(mainchat.msg.value== ""){
            alert("fill in blanks");
            return;
        }
        var uname = $_SESSION['username'];
        var msg = mainchat.msg.value;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("chatlogs").innerHTML = xhttp.reponseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "insert.php?uname="+uname+"&msg="+msg, true);
        xhttp.send();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
            setInterval(function(){
                $("#chatlogs").load("logs.php");}, 2000);
        });
    }
```

[chat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiQt1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place I can see where this could happen is this line:

```
document.getElementById("chatlogs").innerHTML = xhttp.reponseText;
```

One way that reponseText can be undefined is if the return is (or looks like) XML, in which case responseXML is set instead.

A quicky "fix" would be:

```
document.getElementById("chatlogs").innerHTML
    = xhttp.reponseText ? xhttp.reponseText : "";
```

Of course, it's possible the problem is in code you didn't share with us.

Comment: Sir, still it displays undefined!

Comment: Then, I would surmise that it came from something you didn't share with us.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this. And please let me know its helpful for you or not ???

```
document.getElementById("chatlogs").innerHTML = xhttp.reponseText | "";
```

Comment: it's been helpful for testing . sir @yatindra using this code of yours this post displays 0 now instead of previos  undefined

Comment: try this -> 
if(typeof xhttp.reponseText !== 'undefined'){
  document.getElementById("chatlogs").innerHTML = xhttp.reponseText;
}

Comment: same outputs undefined now

Comment: var responseMsg = xhttp.reponseText | '';
if(responseMsg != '' && responseMsg != 0){
 document.getElementById("chatlogs").innerHTML = responseMsg;
}

Comment: What is code in your insert.php what it returns back?

Comment: I believe you meant double pipe (logical OR operator) `||`, not the single (bitwise OR operator) pipe.